# NSMutableArray count equals 0 when add object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have the next code:

```
-(void)accountAdded:(GoogleMailAccount *)account
{
    DLog(@"accountAdded %@ ",account.emailAddress);

     DLog(@"_accounts addObject %@ ",account);
    [_accounts addObject:account];

     DLog(@"_accounts count %d",[_accounts count]);

    [_subFolders setValue:[account subscribedFolders] forKey:account.emailAddress];

    [self refreshTableViewTree];
}
```

and the next log output for it:

```
2013-08-02 00:57:28.009 MailClient[9327:11603] accountAdded iosmailclienttest@gmail.com 
2013-08-02 00:57:28.010 MailClient[9327:11603] _accounts addObject <GoogleMailAccount: 0x7db94f0> 
2013-08-02 00:57:28.011 MailClient[9327:11603] _accounts count 0
```

Why accounts size = 0? (It's a real problem for me :( .What I don't see???)

Comment: Is the array _accounts nil? In ObjC you can send messages to nil, so it wouldn't give an error if it was nil and you called a method on it

Comment: I get it. My bad - I forgot again about the NullPointerException missing in the language. Thanks.

Comment: @Abdullah Shafique  - actually Tom's "Is _accounts != nil?" was enough for understanding my dummy problem. In any case - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In start of method:

```
 if(!_accounts) _accounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Or you can do in:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)accounts
{
    if(!_accounts) _accounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    return _accounts;
}
```

Comment: A better solution would be to do that in the class's designated initializer.

Comment: @bbum That is true but this way works.